# Вывести в консоль квадрат в квадрате со ***

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!
С обычным квадратом все просто, но как в него засунуть поменьше квадрат, вот это проблемка... Помогите пожалуйста)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
//Вывести на экран квадрат в квадрате
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int side;
    cout << "Введите 1 сторону квадрата = ";
    cin >> side;
    for (int i = 1; i <= side ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= side * 2; j++)
        {
            if (i == 1 || j == side * 2 || j == 1 || i == side )
                cout << '*';
            else
                cout << ' ';
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= side; j++)
        {
            if ( i == side / 3)
                cout << '*';
            else
                cout << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

я уже начала подумывать применить третий for со своим if, но условие для этого if не лезет в голову... т.е. 21 строчка не правильная(

Comment: внутренний квадрат 3х3 звездочки в центре? или может быть разного размера и неизвестно где расположен? почему во втором цикле `side * 2` количество итераций?

Comment: Эту задачу сильно проще решить, если сделать одну хитрость - рисовать в памяти. То есть, заводим массив `char a[80][25]` и рисуем на нем все фигуры. А потом, двумя циклами (а можно, если чуточку подумать и одним, и даже без цикла) нарисовать все.

Comment: Привели бы хотя бы, как должен выглядеть результат. Просто, если правильно понимаю, то тут достаточно одного цикла. Это же квадрат :)

Comment: я говорил о циклах для рисования массива на экран. А как рисовать квадрат - это дело известное.

Comment: @KoVadim, да я собственно имел ввиду приведенный пример )

Answer (score 2):

Вот моя реализация вашей задачи.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int k = 0;
    cout << "INPUT SIZE 1: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "INPUT SIZE 2: ";
    cin >> b;

    if(a >= 20 || b >= 20){
        cout << "Size >= 20 ! is err";
        return 0;
    }

    if(a == b){
        cout << "Size 1 == size 2 ! is err";
        return 0;
    }

    if(a > b){
        k = (a - b) / 2;
    }

    if(a < b){
        k = (b - a) / 2;
    }

    char arr[20][20] = {0};

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        arr[i][0] = '*';
        arr[0][i] = '*';
        arr[a-1][i] = '*';
        arr[i][a-1] = '*';
    }

    b += k;
    for(int i=k; i<b; i++){
        arr[i][k] = '*';
        arr[k][i] = '*';
        arr[b-1][i] = '*';
        arr[i][b-1] = '*';
    }

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
            cout << arr[i][j];
       }
       cout << endl;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Скрин результата]

Comment: Квадрат внутренний должен быть по середине наружного квадрата, и нельзя использовать что-то другое, кроме for и if

Comment: Так лучше? надеюсь помог